# Can I put my pressure tank over 200’ from the well head?

Tags: plumbing, well, well-pump

I want to winterize my system which means me moving the pressure tank 200’ to a heated structure. Will this cause any problems I should be aware or plan for?

Comment: It's hard to know without more detail. Is the water being piped to that structure anyway? What is the distance to other structures? Uphill or downhill? Since the tank tee and pressure switch will follow the tank, you'll need to consider the wiring issues as well as the plumbing. Often, a bit of heat tape and some insulation can do the job. What are the coldest winter temperatures you expect to deal with?

Comment: Sub zero temperatures are not uncommon. I intend to run self regulated heat cables between the tank and well head. The tank itself will either be situated in my garden shed or if I can make room the main cottage I intend to service in the winter months. The shed is only 10 yards from the cottage

Comment: Can we assume a submersible pump? Internal or external motor control? I recommend keeping external motor controls as close to the pump as possible. You can run the AC power from the pressure switch to the well head instead of the pump wire. Is this a new installation or a retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

Should not be a problem. Pressure tanks are best located in or near the structure served, not near the well-head.

Mine is ~400 feet of pipe from the pump (300 up and 100 or so sideways.)